# My App keep redirect to login pages after login (MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Everything is ok on my development server and working very well. And the this problem become when I want to put into live server.

In my IIS (7.0), I have parent site with running on asp.net webforms. So my new app is running on this parent site.

The problem is, my app always redirect to login page after login. In url address always show **http://localhost/v2/Authentications/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fv2**. Suppose the url is **http://localhost/v2**

So I already try :

1. Put AllowAnonymous  on actions in controller
2. Change "Anonymous Authentications" from specific user to application pool identity
3. Set inheritInChildApplications to false except `<connectionString>` and `<runtime>` in web.config

But still cannot solved my problem. Any idea?

Comment: is it returning to login page after a succesfull login? Show us your login controller

Comment: If you are redirected back to login it could be a session problem. Check if your session has been destroyed after login.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out.

In my parent website, I open the web config and remove

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

And problem solved.